# Chance of exactly one birthday out of 336 to be January 1st.

Tags: probability

What is the possibility that out of 336 birthdays, exactly one of them is January 1st? I'm assuming not a leap year.

This is what I have so far. If we imagine the list birthdays to be a string, there should be $364^{335}*1$ strings that have all the other birthdays of the year, then January 1st. Then we need to account for reorderings of the string, so we multiply it by ${336\choose1}=336$. Our final probability will be $\frac{364^{335}*336}{365^{336}}\approx0.367198$, which seems way too high. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Your only mistake is to assume that this seems way too high .. :)

Comment: Did I get it right? God forbid I get something right on the first try!

Comment: @umopaplsdn As Hagen von Eitzen already stated (maybe too ironical for you), your result is correct-on the first try.

Answer (score 2):

I'm actually correct. Sorry about misleading people.

Here's the solution from the question:

> If we imagine the list birthdays to be a string, there should be $364^{335}*1$ strings that have all the other birthdays of the year, then January 1st. Then we need to account for reorderings of the string, so we multiply it by ${336\choose1}=336$. Our final probability will be $\frac{364^{335}*336}{365^{336}}\approx0.367198$.

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question.

Comment: @MarkFantini But this does look like a complete answer. The question was: "What did I do wrong?" and the answer is simply "nothing".